# Debug Electron app via Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, electron

Can anyone help me? I am one of the many users who tries to debug an Electron app written in Typescript, but the breakpoints don't work. There are plenty of other threads, but none of them seem to work. Does anyone has a proper result how I can properly set it up? I highly appreciate any help!

[image]

This is so far the `launch.json` I came up with. My breakpoints work in `main.ts`, but not `home.component.ts`.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Electron: Main",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--remote-debugging-port=9223", "."],
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
        "sourceMap": true,
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: In my case it was an outdated Visual Studio Code version